# CSS Help To Position Sale Banner Over Image

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-float, alignment

I am trying to position this sale banner over the image. The red border is a fixed width div that is as wide as I need for the page layout. No matter what the size of the image is, I need to keep a space as wide as this.

The black border is a div that is only as wide as the picture, which I am trying to display the sale banner in the upper right corner on top of the picture.

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/d5nxT/

I know I'm getting something messed up with the displays & positions. I just need the image & sale span to have the same settings, except the sale span floats to the right and has a higher z-index than the image.

Comment: dear see my answer and let me know if any issues you face so i can change the code as per your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the fiddle and demo:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5nxT/2/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d5nxT/2/embedded/result/

float:right, z-index, position:relative, display:inline-block all are not required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `position:absolute` the `sale` span like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymCLe/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the css of the sale span to the following:

```
span.onsale {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 59px;
    height: 59px;
    z-index: 10;
    background: url(http://i42.tinypic.com/sq49ow.png) no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

This way the sale image is place in the top right corner of the parent image (hence the top:0 and right:0 styles)

Answer (score 0):

There are **2** things that need to be done to do this kind of placements flawlessly.

1. You need a positioned (not fixed) element as a parent.
2. Your child needs to become absolute.

If you ensure these 2 things you will be able to position child elements relative to the parent with the top, left, bottom and right properties in css.

For you that probably means `div.interior-images` needs to get the property `position: relative`. And `span.onsale` gets the properties `position: absolute` and `right: 0`.

Your [altered jsfiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/d5nxT/1/)